# Functions, how to call them 3 differente times, with different value

Tags: javascript, function

I´m stuck in this exercise, it seems simple, but I tried to use some of examples that they provide me, but none worked.

They declare me a function:

```
var double = function (x) {
    console.log(x * 2);
};
```

Now they ask me call it three times, each time with a different value and say that "You'll need to use the name we've given to the variable, followed by a number inside a pair of parenthesis."

Being trying to construct this lines based on some examples that I search online, but nothing seems to work, I think I´m not calling the fucntion the right way, can you help me and also provide some lights?
Also please dont jugde my question, I´m new at this and trying my best to learn!

Thanks

UPDATE : RESOLVED Thanks!

Comment: "*I think I´m calling the fucntion the right way*" where have you done that?

Comment: Please share how you are calling the function?

Comment: Sorry I wanted to say I think I´m not calling the right way, saw some examples like this: let x = 5
function f(y) { y = 10; console.log(y)  }
f(x)
console.log(x)  or   let x = 5
function f(x) { x = 10; console.log(x)  }
f(100)
console.log(x)

Comment: Please may you update the question with a [mcve] rather than commenting with code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the instructions and do **exactly** what it tells you.

It doesn't say to declare any variables. So why do you have `let x = ...`.

It doesn't say to use the `function` keyword, so why have you?

Do exactly what it says.

Take the name they have given to the function (i.e. `double`) followed by the number (`5`) inside a pair of parenthesis (`(` and `)`).

```
double(5)
```

and do that three times

```js
var double = function(x) {
  console.log(x * 2);
};

double(5)
double(10)
double(100)
```

Comment: Ya I guess you are right, I was complicating a simple task! Sorry and many thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

I would say just call your function:

```
var double = function (x) {
    console.log(x * 2);
};
double(1);
double(2);
double(3);
```

or

```
var double = function (x) {
    console.log(x * 2);
};
for(let i=0; i < 2; i++){
    double(i);
}
```